# Name fixing / validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Frequently, I have found, users enter very poorly formatted names when they register.  I get all kinds of crazy formatting from Paypal IPN and other payment gateways even from all lower case to all caps to just flat out messed up.

One thing I do with this information is to send out emails and offer greetings, however I dislike the poorly formatted names.  Has someone thought about this before and figured out a happy middle road solution?  For example, I realize it would be poor form to simply correct spellings that are seemingly errors, but it would be wise to at least fix "what is reasonable."  At the minimum that would be capitalization.  Perhaps simply upcasing the first letters of each distinct "word" in the first and last name strings would be sufficient?

Or is there a a better method?  Perhaps a database of common name capitalizations for things like "McBerry" and "van Buuren"?  A gem or some such tool?  Just kind of curious.  Perhaps it is foolish to put this much thought into this topic, but I really like to be as courteous and professional as possible in my communications with users vs just using a poorly formatted name as is the usual.

Comment: There won't be a perfect solution, as my last name can attest. Some people are LaFortune...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can hope to do is capitalize the first letter of their first/last/middle name:

"`bob".capitalize => "Bob"`

From Ruby:

```
capitalize → new_str click to toggle source

Returns a copy of str with the first character converted to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase. Note: case conversion is effective only in ASCII region.

"hello".capitalize    #=> "Hello"
"HELLO".capitalize    #=> "Hello"
"123ABC".capitalize   #=> "123abc"
```

You can also use `downcase` to level everything out, then `capitalize` to make it "right".

For instance:

```
fName = "jIMMY"
lName = "sMITH"

fName.downcase
lName.downcase

fName.capitalize
lNmae.capitalize

puts fName + lName => Jimmy Smith
```

However, with names like `VanBuuren`, it might be a little harder.

Here is a link to Ruby strings which has some methods that might help you on your quest.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html

Comment: Yeah, this is already what I had in mind.  Was just hopeful for something a little more insightful or with more coverage.